# Backbone Marionette Difference between CompositeView & CollectionView?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I see that both share almost the same properties & functions so what is the main difference for these two?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That question is addressed here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Use-cases-for-the-different-views

In short, you'll want to use CompositeView if you want to wrap a template around the collection (ex: a list with a header and footer). CollectionView doesn't know how to render a template.

Comment: also, a CompositeView defaults to using itself for the items it renders from the collection. this makes it hierarchical / recursive by default.

Comment: Here's the `CompositeView` documentation (v2.4.7) that covers this use case: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.compositeview.html

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.marionettejs.com/2016/08/23/marionette-v3/index.html

> Version 2.x had many different kinds of views: View, ItemView,
>   LayoutView, CollectionView, CompositeView.
>
> In version 3 ItemView, and LayoutView were ‘merged’ into View, and
>   CompositeView was deprecated for removal in v4. Now we have only View
>   and CollectionView.

and layouts  were  removed too